# How does postgreql manage added or changed columns involved in table publication?

Tags: postgresql

I've managed to `CREATE PUBLICATION` ( and corresponding `SUBSCRIPTION` ) for a set of tables in my database. It's all working wonderfully. Now someone wants to add a column to one of the base tables (ayayay) and I can't seem to find any documentation regarding how to (most-easily) manage this situation and I'm hoping someone can lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a column is easy:

- First, add the column on the standby. That won't break replication; the new column will remain empty.
- Then, add the column on the primary.

If you change the set of tables that is replicated, don't forget to run

```
ALTER SUBSCRIPTION ... REFRESH PUBLICATION;
```